# Is java Arraylist a form of Composition

Tags: java, arraylist

When we make ArrayList of objects of a class,let's say we have a class `Cirlce` and we store its contents in Arraylist `c`. Will it be considered as Composition? Since an ArrayList is a class in java.

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54988783/is-arraylistx-an-aggregation-or-composition

Answer (score 0):

No, an ArrayList of Circle is a collection of Circle instances. It does not contain a Circle object in its [source code](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java).